# vba mssql connection error

Tags: sql-server, vba

I am trying to connect sql with Access.
What I want to do is simply get data from mssql using select statement.
Here is the code.

```
Sub ConnectSQLServer()

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String
Dim par As ADODB.Parameter
Dim strSQL As String


strConn = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=CHU-AS-0004;DATABASE=RTC_LaplaceD_DEV;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.Version"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Version"


cmd.Execute
conn.Close

Set conn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I execute this code, I get error like "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] The request for procedure 'Version' failed because 'Version' is a table object.'

I know that I need to add something after "strSQL = SELECT * FROM dbo.Version" but I do not know exactly how to fill in.
Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are executing **dbo.Version** as a SP or a SQL Command which is wrong.

You should execute the command in **strSQL** object instead. So after the modifications your code will look something like this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Version"

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
```

**EDIT 1**

I replicated the same issue in MS Excel to read data from MS SQl Server by using the following code and it worked for me:

```
 'Declare variables'
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=HARSH-SHARMA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db1;User ID=sa;Password=pass001;"
    objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    strSQL = "select * from Subject"

'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

'Copy Data to Excel'
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
```

Please try this.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! But when I fix that code, I get following error...:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Syntax error or access violation. Do you know how to solve this error, too?

Comment: Are you connectting Access/Excel (VB6) to MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, connecting Access and mssql server

Comment: I just modified my actual post and posted new code, please try this, it will work for you.